# How can I bookmark a chat?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, chat-bookmarks

I am unaware of the feature for bookmarking a chat on Stack Overflow. I saw some users having a bookmark of a particular part of chat in the room. So, from where can we bookmark a particular part of chat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's explained in the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq), in the [Can I share a link to a specific message? Or range of messages?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#permalink) section:

> Sure; if you click the menu button against any message, you get the "permalink" option:
>
> [image: image from the FAQ]
>
> This gives you a link directly to that message, highlighting that message for clarity. If you want to create a link to a *group* of messages, you can bookmark a block of conversation by choosing "create new bookmark" from the room menu:
>
> [image: image from the FAQ]
>
> Then just follow the simple on-screen instructions to select the messages you want to include. You need at least 100 reputation to create a new bookmark.

Comment: Where can we find a bookmark after we create it?

Comment: @LalitPoptani It's on the room's info page (there's a link in the right sidebar), in the "Conversations" tab

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning (at least here in comments) that when a bookmark is created, it is added to two places - [conversation tab of the room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=conversations) and also [conversation tab in the chat profile](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard?tab=conversations) of the user who created the bookmark. (I have linked one random example for both.)

Answer (score 3):

1. Hover over a chat message and click the small arrow that appears.
2. There will be a link at the top of the pop-up that appears. Use your browser to bookmark this link.

[image: permalink to chat message]