# Add threaded view to chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ability to see linked chat messages separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151419/ability-to-see-linked-chat-messages-separately)

In busy chat rooms, it's not uncommon to have multiple simultaneous conversations going on.

We already have the direct reply feature, which is a very handy way to link a message to a previous message.

Would it make sense/is it possible to expand this a step further, and add a "thread" view?  Basically an additional option to see ALL related messages in a conversation of linked messages, instead of just the last one?

I'm envisioning this working similar to the history links, that show a cached version of a message in a new window.