# Chat highlighting should work in transcripts as in actual chat

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, chat, highlighting

In an active chat room, on the desktop chat client, hovering the mouse pointer over a message puts a lightweight line around that message. Furthermore, if that message a reply to another, or if there are replies to that message, the other messages in the reply chain are highlighted (with a dark background) as well.

In chat *transcripts*, the thin-line-on-this-message highlighting takes place, but the darker-related-messages highlighting does not. This makes it harder to follow a conversation in the transcript of a crowded room than it is in the room itself --- to the extent that sometimes I will from the chat transcript to the chat room and select "load older messages" an unreasonable number of times to make sure that I understand who was talking to whom.

Is the different treatment of these displays an intentional choice?  Could the related-messages highlighting be enabled in the transcript as well?  A client-side userscript would be okay, but I use enough different computers that I would prefer something on the server side.

[This similar feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180109/280545) doesn't seem to exist for me, and seems like it might have some problematic characteristics if it did.

Comment: I've made an update to my [ChatTranscriptHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ChatTranscriptHelper.user.js) userscript to highlight message replies to as well as the message that was replied to (like live chat)